# datepicker with ng-repeat in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker

I am writing one application where i need to show4 different date and Start/End Time.
So i have created date using datepicker. Below that i have one checkbox ,If user checks that check box it will  add same set of date(default) So the maximum date would be 4.

So i tried using ng-repeat but seems some issue.

Kindly help

```
        <div class="form-group">
                          <label>6. Enter Onsite Details( Up to 4)</label> <br>
                        <div ng-repeat="object in configDate track by $index"> 

                          <button bs-datepicker
                                  class="btn btn-info"
                                  id="comm_cal_bttn"
                                  name="date"
                                  data-animation="am-flip-x"
                                  data-autoclose="true"
                                  data-max-date="{{comm.maxDate}}"
                                  data-min-date="{{comm.minDate}}"
                                  ng-blur="getMinTime();"
                                  ng-model="scheduled.commDate">
                            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i> Date
                          </button>
                          <br>
                          <br>
                          <button bs-timepicker
                                  class="btn btn-info"
                                  id="comm_time_bttn"
                                  name="Start Time"
                                  data-animation="am-flip-x"
                                  data-length="3"
                                  data-minute-step="{{comm.minuteStep}}"
                                  data-round-display="true"
                                  min-time="{{comm.minTime}}"
                                  ng-blur="checkValidTime();"
                                  ng-disabled="! scheduled.commDate"
                                  ng-keydown="disableKeys();"
                                  ng-model="scheduled.commTime">
                            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Start Time
                          </button>
                          &nbsp;
                          &nbsp;
                          <button bs-timepicker
                                  class="btn btn-info"
                                  id="comm_time_bttn"
                                  name="End Time"
                                  data-animation="am-flip-x"
                                  data-length="3"
                                  data-minute-step="{{comm.minuteStep}}"
                                  data-round-display="true"
                                  min-time="{{comm.minTime}}"
                                  ng-blur="checkValidTime();"
                                  ng-disabled="! scheduled.commDate"
                                  ng-keydown="disableKeys();"
                                  ng-model="scheduled.commTime">
                            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> End Time
                          </button>
                          <br>
                          <br>
                         </div>
                         <label for="cc_user">Location</label> <input type="text"  ng-model="configDate"> 
                        <br>
                        <br>
                          <input type="checkbox"  ng-model="configDate" ng-checked = "configDate.push(configDate)"> <label for="cc_user">Add Additional</label>
                        </div>
```

Comment: I would recommend you to prepare jsFiddle with some more code, including the controller or at least the data model that you are using. It is hard to see from the markup only.

Comment: you are using configDate ng-model for location text field and checkbox why ?, and also add controller code.

Comment: Sir my only concern is on each checkbox checked i want to add one div(date-picker, timepicker). So how to do that? I am pretty much new to Angular.

Comment: @savvv please be more specific, you want to add the same date when the check box is checked or you will have 4 dates with 4 checkboxes

Comment: @MBalajivaishnav- Bro on each time when a user checks this check box It should add one same date. And maximum count will be 4 time a user can check checkbox.